# Many 4 character storage containers being created in my storage account

Tags: azure-storage

I have an Azure storage account.

For a while now, something has been creating 4 character empty containers as shown here, there are hundreds of them:

[image]

This storage account is used by:

- Function Apps
- Document Db (Cosmos)
- Terraform State
- Container Registry for Docker images

It's not a big deal but I don't want millions of empty containers being created by an unknown process.

**Note1**: I have looked for any way to find more statistics / history of these folders but I cant find any

**Note2**: We don't have any custom code that creates storage containers in our release pipelines (ie... PowerShell or CLI)

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the containers are used to store logs of **Azure Function**. I have a storage account just for azure function and web app. We could see it has the containers like yours via Storage Explorer.

[image]

Comment: thanks for that but are your containers empty as all of mine are empty. Therefore I don't see why an azure function would create many empty Containers without any log files in them

Comment: @RuSs Yes, but the containers were not empty from the beginning, I considered this before and checked these containers, there were log files in them, it seems they have expired.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for your help